# How much is the gain of this Op Amp?

Tags: current

[image: My circuit]

I have a circuit like this. I want to calculate the gain of this circuit. If there is no R4 then it is easy to calculate.But now I have a problem. If I have a input current I=0.5A, then what is the output current or voltage ?

Sorry, last resistance is 50 ohm.  not 100.

Comment: The behaviour of the system aside from the output resistor is the same whether or not the output resistor is there (the - input to the opamp is tied to 0V and absorbs no current). The opamp's output should act like a voltage source with no source impedance. So, by putting the 50 ohm resistor at the output, you simply add to the source impedance. Therefore, the gain you achieve depends on what you are driving if you're driving an infinite resistance, your gain is unchanged: think of Thévenin equivalent ideal voltage source, set by the gain of the opamp circuit and  a 50 ohm Thévenin impedance.

Comment: Would [electronics.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: This circuit WILL NOT work with an input current of 0.5 amps!! Please revise your expectations.

Comment: Why would someone say that "R2 does nothing" and "is silly?" This is commonly done to balance the input bias currents, isn't it? I was taught since the '70s to always include this to reduce offsets.

Comment: The TL081 is a JFET input part with an input bias current of 10 nA worst case. The DC offset caused by this current and value of resistors would be minuscule compared to the input offset voltage.

Comment: This does not try to answer *[at] input current I=0.5 A, [what] is the output current or voltage?* Please [do not use Your Answer to post a follow-on question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers): [Ask a Good Question of your own](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: (same reflex (and time frame) here - while in this particular case the current and resistor values combine to make the resistor pointless, I learned there are design habits advantageous to a) follow, and b) deviate from in well-checked cases - if in software development, and occasionally the rough way.)

Comment: @JoePolizzi Please ask this as a new question with a link to this one if you wish to pursue it. This site has a strict one question, multiple answers format rather than a forum system. BUT - Olin, who aid that is no longer on this site. He is exceptionally competent but sometimes a bit rough in wording. What he meant is that IN THIS APPLICATION R2 has such a minimal effect that it would be completely buried in the noise. He explains why. 
I'll change this post to a comment. You are very welcome to either ask a new question about this or to post other questions or answers.

Answer (score 2):

*In theory*, this is basically a inverting amplifier with gain of 1 (overall gain of -1).  However, in practise there are significant problems with this circuit:

You forgot to hookup power!  Opamps need separate power to work, and in your case it needs both a positive and negative supply.  Note that the TL081 requires significant output headroom at each end.  The power supply voltage matters, and tells us what operating range you are expecting.

R2 does nothing.  The TL081 is a FET input opamp, so 50 Ω in series with one of its inputs is just silly.  The positive input of the opamp is tied to ground either way.

R1 and R3 are connected around the opamp in classic inverting amplifier configuration.  The gain is always negative, and its magnitude is R3/R1, which in this case is 1.  However, you also have to consider the current capability of the opamp.  100 Ω is very low, and will require significant current.  I haven't looked it up (that's your job), but I expect the TL081 is only good for a few 10s of mA.  It might work over its whole range with 1 kΩ resistors, but likely not with 100 Ω resistors.  Since you haven't connected power, and we therefore don't know what voltage range you expect this to work over, we can't really say what will happpen.

100 Ω is a very heavy output load for a TL081.  Again, look up the current capability of the opamp.

What's the point of the 100 Ω output resistor (Argh, no component designator!)?  Even if the other issues above are solved, we can only guarantee the circuit function from the input to the opamp output.  What happens at Output is also a function of the load, which you don't show.

Your statement of 500 mA input current makes no sense at all.  Actually *think* about it.  (500 mA)(100 Ω) = 50 V.  That's how much would be across each of R1 and R3.  While you could get a 100 Ω resistor that can take 50 V and dissipate 25 W, 50 V is way out of spec for being between any two terminals of a TL081.

TI publishes a datasheet for this part for a reason.  Read it.

Answer (score 1):

The (open loop) gain of this OPAMP is given in its datasheet, but despite the title of your question, that is not what you want to know. For practical purposes, at audio (or lower) frequencies where its internal compensation and parasitics do not matter, its gain is sufficiently close to infinite and delay-free to assume that it suffices to keep both inputs at the same voltage. That voltage is ground in your circuit. That knowledge is enough to derive the gain of the entire circuit, which is what you seem to be really after.

The closed loop voltage gain is given by \$- R_3 / R_1 = -1\$ because the point between the two resistors is at (virtual) ground. Your 50$\Ohm$ resistor only limits your output current and hence, as a ratio with your circuit's input resistance, defines a current gain of \$- R1 / R4 = -2\$.

Comment: Have you checked that a TL081 has flat open loop gain at all audio frequencies because you may be surprised.

Comment: No, I haven't, but if it curiously had flat open loop gain, that would cause me to doubt my argument (that it maintains a gain-bandwidth product of at least 1 MHz or so such that over audio frequencies at a close to unity gain it can be approximated as sufficiently high gain as to be essentially infinite).